# jQuery add class based on paren data attribute

Tags: jquery, addclass

How can I assign class to each children in the following scenario:

Read data option value, and assign the same class name to children ul

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li data-option="first"> <a href="#">First Item</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-option="second"> <a href="#">Second Item</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#">Third Item</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

The expected result should be:

```
<ul id="menu">
  <li data-option="first"> <a href="#">First Item</a>
    <ul class="first">
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li data-option="second"> <a href="#">Second Item</a>
    <ul class="second">
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> <a href="#">Third Item</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Second level link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Notice that last li dos not have data-option attribute.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

another one to collection, filtering only the data-option li, reuse $ul object as much as possible

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#menu>li[data-option]').each(function() {
        var $ul = $(this);
        $ul.find('ul').addClass($ul.data('option'));
    });
});
```

Comment: Just to note, the format `$().ready( handler )` is not recommended. See http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [has attribute selector (`[]`)](http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) to test for an attribute presence:

```
$('li[data-option]').each(function () {
    var dataOption = $(this).attr('data-option');
    $(this).find('ul').addClass(dataOption);
});
```

[Check demo here](http://jsbin.com/lodulitu).

**Note:** You could use `.data('option')` instead of `.attr('data-option')`. It is a matter of choice, really. In this case I used `.attr()` because `.data()` is more of a "storage" than an attribute accessor function - and, as you are plainly accessing the `data-option` attribute, with no conversion from the string value, the `.attr()` function seems to denote your intention in the code better.

Comment: both answers are good, this is a little bit faster, but you can use .data for this instead of attr ;)

Comment: @morvy Yes, it is possible. I attempted to include the reason why I preferred `.attr()`. But `.data()` is equally appliable. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do this:

```
$('#menu > li').filter('[data-option]').each(function(){
   $(this).find('ul').addClass($(this).data('option');
});
```

using `filter` is good for performance as it allows jquery to use native `querySelector`.